# Como puedo iterar las propiedades dentro de un objeto en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

Tengo una duda, ¿Como puedo iterar entre objetos que comparten el mismo nombre pero cambian en el numero al final?.

Ejemplo:

```
windows.lineEdit1.setText("ejemplo")
windows.lineEdit1.setText("ejemplo")
windows.lineEdit1.setText("ejemplo")
```

Intente hacerlo con un for, pero no es posible hacerlo, Logre sacar el atributo, pero pensadlo bien no me sirve de nada porque vuelvo al ejemplo anterior. Para que se me pueda entender lo hice de esta manera.

```
for x in range(0,30):
windows.lineEditx.setText("ejemplo")
```

Ahora, se me ocurrio una idea: Podría generar una string que contenga lo que deseo

```
command = 'windows.lineEdit1_' + str(x) +'.setHidden(True)' #Donde x se reemplaza por los numeros del for, 0 1 2 3 4 5..
exec(command)
```

Al usar `exec(command)` logro settear todos los campos a los que desee o hacer otra cosa.

A pesar de que funciona algo me dice que esta implementan no esta bien y no debería hacerse, buscando en google no he encontrado respuesta.

Gracias de antemano,
Saludos

Comment: Pon los objetos en una lista; itera sobre la lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luego de buscar y de pedir ayuda a un amigo con mucha experiencia llegue a la solucion :

Podemos usar `findChild` que trae por defecto, Aqui el codigo:

```
for y in range(1, len(processList)+1):
    child = windows.scrollArea.findChild(QLineEdit, 'lineEdit1_' + str(y))
    child.setHidden(False)
```

Esto itera entre todos los elementos que esten dentro de un groupBox como scrollArea que tengan el atributo QLineEdit.

Gracias por leer!

Comment: Pero ... ¡¡ eso **no es** lo que tu has preguntado !! Eso es la forma de iterar sobre elementos `QObject` **hijos** de otro `QObject.`. En la pregunta das a entender que quieres iterar sobre los *atributos* de un Objeto python cualquiera. O al menos es lo que yo entendí.

Comment: Probablemente por lo novato que soy se habra malentendido o lo abre escrito mal, bueno, Gracias por la aclaracion, pense que la pregunta estaba bien formulada pero hasta eso estaba mal!

Comment: @FernandoBarrueto otra opcion es: `getattr(windows, "lineEdit{}".format(y)).setText("ejemplo")`